# dotnet 6 swagger not picking up authorization

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7gEKqSlb40
and got all the app registrations working. After I log in via Swagger, it seems that swagger is not passing on the authorization to the controller.

This is the piece of code:

```
{
    config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Test", Version = "V1" });
    config.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        
        Description = "OAuth2 which uses authorization flow",
        Name = "OAuth2",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:AuthorozationUrl"]),
                TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:TokenUrl"]),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:Scope"], "Access API as user" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2"}
        },
        new []  {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:Scope"]}
        }
    });
});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:ClientId"]);
        c.OAuthUsePkce();
        c.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
    });
}
```

As I am able to login:
[image: swagger login]

but my endpoint seems to think it is not needed:
[image: swagger call to endpoint]

any clue what I am doing wrong?

this is my code in controller:
standard generated:

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and like always, it was a really stupid typo.

in this piece:

```
 config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    {
    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Reference = new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2"}
    },
    new []  {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAzureAD:Scope"]}
    }
});
```

the Id was wrong and needs to be: `OAuth2`
Then it is being picked up.